# how to avoid a faulty rollback migration in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rollback

i have a bug in a "self.drop" in a migration such that I cannot roll back past that migration. how can i start from scratch and build up from migration 001? also, is there a way to do this without losing my data (it's just testing, but still...)

Comment: It depends on how you changed the database in that migration. Added something? Deleted somthing? Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment all statements in self.down migration and rollback to previous db version.

Then apply changes by hand using a gui/web db client to match db schema before migration.

After you will be able to run migration again and your data will not be lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

It will reset your database and run all migrations. If you don't want to lose your data you can save it using plugin [yaml_db](http://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db/tree/master):

```
rake db:data:dump  # stores all data in db/data.yml
...
rake db:data:load  # loads db/data.yml to database
```

If you have an error in a migration you can edit it and then try to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but imho still relevant. If you want to recreate your database from scratch, one does not rollback and rerun migration, one just does

```
rake db:setup
```

This will drop, create and fill the database with the current combined state of all the migrations. This is because, definitely in a large system, running all the migrations might no longer work. However, running the `schema.rb` will always work.

My advice would also be to avoid rollback of migrations as much as possible, unless when you just created a migration and want to make some addition/typo/fix, before having pushed the migration to your team or any deployment.